# Mysql group_concact what am i doing wrong

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to get all favorite users of a particular user using this simple sub-query

```
select * from users u 
where u.user_id in 
(
    select GROUP_CONCAT(f.favorite_id SEPARATOR ',') as favourites 
    from favourite_user f
    where f.user_id in(14) group by user_id 
)
```

When I run the subquery `select GROUP_CONCAT(f.favorite_id SEPARATOR ',') as favourites 
        from favourite_user f
        where f.user_id in(14) group by user_id` it gives me result `6,8,11,10,13,15,7,12`

and when i run this query `select * from users u 
where u.user_id in (6,8,11,10,13,15,7,12)` it is returning **7 rows** of result

But when i run the above mentioned main query it is just giving me the **1 row** (the first one) instead of 7.

Can anyone explain me what am i doing wrong. I know this can also be done with joins but I'd like to know why this approach isn't working

Thank you in advance

Comment: any specific reason you need to use group_concat ?

Comment: `group_concat` gives you a single string as result. This will not work with `in`. `in` needs seperate ids.

Comment: @ArunKumarM I thought in required comma separeted ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Try

```
select * 
  from users
 where user_id in 
(
    select favorite_id 
      from favourite_user
     where user_id = 14
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7462d/1)** demo